# Regular expression safety

Tags: regex, perl

Is this enough safety for preventing an undefined variable from making its way into my script?

```
    # Find the name of the VMXF file
$getfilelayout =~ /^ \s+ " (?<vmxf_file> .+\.vmxf) " /xm;

if ("$+{vmxf_file}" eq '') {
    $vmxf_file = 'undef';
} else {
    $vmxf_file = "$+{vmxf_file}";
    $vmxf_file = $ssh_obj->capture("find -name $vmxf_file");
}
```

If not, what else could I do?

Comment: @mu is too short, this seems to be the way to access named back references [Perlretut#Named-backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences)

Comment: You should not assume the match succeeded, so put it in an `if`.  Also, you don’t have to quote your named captures: `$+{vmxf_file}` retrieves it just fine.

Comment: @ tchrist, I don't have to quote the captures? Cool. I originally had the match inside an if statement but it seemed unnecessary, but now looking at with you input I could see why that would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not assume the match succeeded, so put it in an `if`. Also, you don’t have to quote your named captures: `$+{vmxf_file}` retrieves it just fine. Here I assume that the filename does not have whitespace or quotes in it:

```
use 5.010;

if ($getfilelayout =~ /^ \h+ " (?<vmxf_file> ["\s]+ \.vmxf) " /xm) {
    $captcha = $+{vmxf_file};
    $found   = $ssh_obj->capture("find -name $captcha");
}
```

The "safety" issue is that you don’t know what sort of metachars are in the capture. The right way would be to use something more like

```
system("find", "-name", $captcha);
```

but that doesn’t capture your output.  I don’t think the ssh protocol allows for safe shelling, but I don’t know.  What class are you using?

Comment: whats `\h+` do? Have not seen that one.

Comment: I have to use SSH because the data that is being matched does not reside on the localhost its on a VMware server on my network.

Comment: he is probably using Net::OpenSSH that does support "safe shelling"

Comment: @Solignis: `\h` is horizontal white space. It appears in 5.010, when named captures also appeared.

Comment: @Salva, yeah I am using Net::OpenSSH.

Answer (score 1):

```
# An undefined variable might not be your only worry!?!
my $getfilelayout = q{  " '*' | xargs rm ; echo .vmxf" };

# A regex in list context returns the captures.
# IMHO, this seems cleaner than what you've got.
my ($vmxf_file) = $getfilelayout =~ /^\s+ "(.+\.vmxf)"/xm;

# Proceed accordingly.
if (defined $vmxf_file){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oo I like that, so that variable is only defined if the match succeeds.